# Unable to connect to any of the specified MySQL hosts. when trying to connect mysql

Tags: mysql

im using go daddy vps , installed mysql configured /etc/my.cnf to look like this:

```
[mysqld]
user=mysql
datadir=/var/lib/mysql
socket=/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock
port=3306
# bind-address=1xx.1xx.1xx.148
bind-address=1xx.1xx.1xx.148
skip-networking

# Default to using old password format for compatibility with mysql 3.x
# clients (those using the mysqlclient10 compatibility package).
old_passwords=1

# Disabling symbolic-links is recommended to prevent assorted security risks;
# to do so, uncomment this line:
# symbolic-links=0

[mysqld_safe]
log-error=/var/log/mysqld.log
pid-file=/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid
```

then when i see in /var/log/mysql.log i see the mysql started right :

```
120113 03:58:59  mysqld started
120113  3:58:59 [Warning] option 'max_join_size': unsigned value 18446744073709551615 adjusted to 4294967295
120113  3:58:59 [Warning] option 'max_join_size': unsigned value 18446744073709551615 adjusted to 4294967295
120113  3:58:59  InnoDB: Started; log sequence number 0 43665
120113  3:58:59 [Note] /usr/libexec/mysqld: ready for connections.
Version: '5.0.77'  socket: '/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock'  port: 3306  Source distribution
```

but when i do :

```
/usr/sbin/lsof -i:3306
```

i dont see any thing.
when i do :

```
 netstat -a |grep LISTEN

tcp        0      0 localhost.localdomain:smtp  *:*                         LISTEN
tcp        0      0 *:http                      *:*                         LISTEN
tcp        0      0 *:ssh                       *:*                         LISTEN
tcp        0      0 *:https                     *:*                         LISTEN
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     244331015 /var/run/saslauthd/mux
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     247310795 /var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock
```

so i see somekind of mysql socked listen ...
but when i try to connect from my Toad to the remote server im getting :
**Unable to connect to any of the specified MySQL hosts.**

im connecting to the mysql root user . to my application db in port 3306.
also i found in the net allot of post saying to remove the skip-networking.
but when i do so . im getting this error when i try to start the Db :

```
120113 14:46:36  mysqld started
120113 14:46:36 [Warning] option 'max_join_size': unsigned value 18446744073709551615 adjusted to 4294967295
120113 14:46:36 [Warning] option 'max_join_size': unsigned value 18446744073709551615 adjusted to 4294967295
120113 14:46:36  InnoDB: Started; log sequence number 0 43665
120113 14:46:36 [ERROR] Can't start server: Bind on TCP/IP port: Cannot assign requested address
120113 14:46:36 [ERROR] Do you already have another mysqld server running on port: 3306 ?
120113 14:46:36 [ERROR] Aborting

120113 14:46:36  InnoDB: Starting shutdown...
120113 14:46:37  InnoDB: Shutdown completed; log sequence number 0 43665
120113 14:46:37 [Note] /usr/libexec/mysqld: Shutdown complete

120113 14:46:37  mysqld ended
```

and i do not have any mysql runnning on this port or any mysql running at all ..
what is wrong here ?

Comment: FYI, godaddy has been supporting SOPA.

Answer (score 4):

What do you think `skip-networking` means? Remove this statement and it should work. See [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/server-options.html#option_mysqld_skip-networking) for the explanation.

Comment: when i disable / comment this param im getting :
120113 14:46:36  InnoDB: Started; log sequence number 0 43665
120113 14:46:36 [ERROR] Can't start server: Bind on TCP/IP port: Cannot assign requested address
120113 14:46:36 [ERROR] Do you already have another mysqld server running on port: 3306 ?
120113 14:46:36 [ERROR] Aborting
and there is no more mysql running in my server

Answer (score -2):

1. C:\Program Files (x86)\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.0\bin
2. click on MySQLInstanceConfig.exe
3. Reconfigure your mysql

Note: This process will not effect your database.

Comment: If you are going to add an answer to a very old question, it needs to be of notably high quality to the general reader.